# CardsUI library setTextSize by clicking on an actionbar button

Tags: android

I am usin the CardsUI library taken from here: http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/cardsui/ 
and trying to change the textview size for all the cards by pressing a button.

At the moment i haven't used any buttons, just wanted to check if my approach is correct by setting a fixed textsize.

I have created:

**MainActivity.java**

```
MyCard androidViewsCard = new MyCard("Title","Description");
androidViewsCard.setSize(20.0f);
```

**MyCard.java**

```
public void setSize(float f) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.getAppContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, null);

    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);

    tv.setTextSize(f);

}
```

The text does not change size though. Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a unit with it.

You need to use the function `setTextSize(unit, size)` with unit SP like this,

```
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, f);//tv is textView
```